# PHP : Protect account-activation script from abuse

Tags: php, database, activation-codes

I made a PHP script for user to activate their account after they clicked on the confirmation-link. It works as usual - the user click on the link

```
www.example.org/activation?code=R4nD0mCoD3
```

The script checks in the database if the code exists and if not it redirect the user to ./index.php

So what is the best solution that people can't spam codes to that site and bring down my database ?

Is there any useful work-a-round ? Sadly I wasnt able to find something in StackOverflow about it yet.

Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: From the top of my head you could log the IP and see if the user accesses the link within a certain amount of time.

Comment: Well the codes should be random enough so that they can't spam codes and activate a random account (Usually activation links expire too). Also, just spamming shouldn't bring down your database anyways.

Comment: Hash the heck out of it, with a time-allotment, then delete upon first/single use. IP's can change, so it's not fully reliable.

Comment: I would make the code long ... as in 64 characters or more

Comment: @simpe : I had this idea also in mind, but I hoped someone could have another idea - since it's again about querys sending to my database

Comment: People spamming the activation URL shouldn't be much of a problem for two reasons: 1. It's a fairly light query. It's just a simple select statement. If someone was doing it maliciously in an effort to DDOS you, there are much better ways to do it. 2. There's no real point in spamming the URL in an effort to mass-activate accounts, so in all likelihood no one would. Even if they did, it doesn't matter.

Comment: How about that takes you to a page with a RE-CAPTCHA which must be entered before it really checks the activation number

Comment: @Samsquanch - well make sense. Looks like I made a fuss out of something which shouldn't be a security problem.

Comment: @cmorrissey yea had that also in mind. But to be honest I don't like using Captcha's at all (even tho I have to use em on logins after x failed trys), cause they are so not userfriendly.

Comment: @Kris they are also not bot friendly

Comment: @cmorrissey yea true. everything got it's pro and cons - but today, it seems, that websites are all about being user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key = sha1($email.time()); // 'email' or any other value
```

Will give you a 40 character key which should be secure enough, but if you really want to prevent a select for any request with a key, you can return a view with a submit button (disabled by default), then enabled using javascript on document.ready as most bots aren't javascript enabled.

If you go that route, you could also set a 1 or 2 second timeout before enabling the button which will slow down the javascript enabled bots.

As mentioned above though, Its a light query, so you don't have too much to worry about as long as you have a secure activation key.